# Kivy self.root.ids.login_pass.text = "" AttributeError: 'FireBase' object has no attribute 'root'

Tags: python, firebase, kivy, kivymd

So i have a class called Firebase where i call google's api it looks something like this

```
class FireBase:
    def sign_up(self, username, email, password):
        ...
        ...
    def poggers(self):
        self.root.ids.login_pass.text = ""
```

In my login.kv file i have something like this:

```
        Button:
            ...
            ...
            on_press:
                app.firebase.poggers()
```

And the TextInput box:

```
            TextInput:
                id: login_pass
                hint_text: "Password"
```

And whenever i press the button it does't set the text to "" as it supposed to but it displays: "     self.root.ids.login_pass.text = ""
AttributeError: 'FireBase' object has no attribute 'root'"

I've tried many solutions and searched it up but i am unsure of what is going on and i don't know how to fix it.

Edit:
A bit more to my MainApp:

```
class MainApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        self.firebase = FireBase()
        screen_manager = ScreenManager()
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv-files/main.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv-files/login.kv"))
        screen_manager.add_widget(Builder.load_file("kv-files/signup.kv"))
        return screen_manager
```

Answer (score 0):

To access with widgets from your `App` class, you need to use `self.root.ids.blablabla...`, but accessing your widgets in other classes and the story goes like this: you use `self.ids.blablabla...` instead:

```python
def poggers(self):
    self.ids.login_pass.text = ""
```